# Cats and Dogs at the Petshop

Tags: c#, object-oriented

I had a test before and had to do this task:

> Create classes: `Cat`, `Dog` and `Petshop`. Types `Cat` and `Dog` have fields `Name` and `Breed` and method `Introduce()` which prints text "I'm (Name) of (Breed). I'm a cat (or dog)".
>
> The class `Petshop` collects different pets in its container.
>   We may add new pet to container using method `AddPet()`, and we may display information about all pets by calling method `IntroduceAll()`.
>
> Which hierarchy of classes is the best solution of this problem?
>
> Write short code to demonstrate your solution. Your code should include class (interface) aggregation, inheritance, should use .NET BCL collections or generics, and should implement exception handling.

**My answer:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    interface IPet
    {       
        string MyName { get; set; }
        string MyBreed { get; set; }
        void Introduce();
    }
```

**`Cat`**

```
    class Cat : IPet
    {
        string Name;
        string Breed;

        public Cat()
        {
            Name = "";
            Breed = "";                
        }

        public string MyName
        {
            get
            {
                return Name;
            }
            set
            {
                Name = value;
            }
        }

        public string MyBreed
        {
            get
            {
                return Breed;
            }
            set
            {
                Breed = value;
            }
        }

        public void Introduce()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I'm " + Name + " of " + Breed + " I'm a cat");
        }        
    }
```

**`Dog`**

```
    class Dog : IPet
    {
        public string Name;
        public string Breed;

        public Dog()
        {
            Name = "";
            Breed = "";
        }

        public string MyName
        {
            get
            {
                return Name;
            }
            set
            {
                Name = value;
            }
        }

        public string MyBreed
        {
            get
            {
                return Breed;
            }
            set
            {
                Breed = value;
            }
        }

        public void Introduce()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I'm " + Name + " of " + Breed + " I'm a dog");
        }        
    }
```

**`PetShop`**

```
    class PetShop
    {
        List<Object> objList = new List<object>();
        public void AddPet(Object obj)
        {
            objList.Add(obj);
        }
        public void IntroduceAll()
        {

            foreach (object element in objList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("One more");
                Type mytype = element.GetType();
                if (mytype == typeof(Cat))
                {
                    var el = (Cat)element;
                    el.Introduce();
                }
                else if (mytype == typeof(Dog))
                {
                    var el = (Dog)element;
                    el.Introduce();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new NotFoundException();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**`Program`**

```
    class Program
    {        
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Cat pussy = new Cat();
            pussy.MyName = "Murlon";
            pussy.MyBreed = "Supernatural";
            Dog doggy = new Dog();
            doggy.MyName = "Oscar";
            doggy.MyBreed = "Blonde";
            Cat pussy1 = new Cat();
            pussy.MyName = "Murlon1";
            pussy.MyBreed = "Supernatural1";
            Dog doggy1 = new Dog();
            doggy.MyName = "Oscar1";
            doggy.MyBreed = "Blonde1";
            //Console.WriteLine(pussy.MyBreed);
            //pussy.Introduce();            
            PetShop ps = new PetShop();
            Exception ex = new Exception();
            ps.AddPet(pussy);
            ps.AddPet(doggy);
            ps.AddPet(pussy1);
            ps.AddPet(doggy1);
            ps.AddPet(ex);
            try
            {
                ps.IntroduceAll();
            }
            catch (NotFoundException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exeption");
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

**`NotFoundException`**

```
    class NotFoundException : Exception
    {
        /* Implement all of the Exception constructors. Notice that 
        the constructors simply execute the base class constructor. 
        Because NotFoundException adds nothing to Exception, 
        there is no need for any further actions. */
        public NotFoundException() : base() { }
        public NotFoundException(string message) : base(message) { }
        public NotFoundException(string message, Exception innerException) :
            base(message, innerException) { }
        protected NotFoundException(
        System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo info,
        System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext context) :
            base(info, context) { }
    }
}
```

I scored 7.8 out of 10. Test was auditing remotely and I haven't had an opportunity to get explanations about the mark.

What could I have done to improve on my answer to get a better rating?

Comment: I would have used a `List<IPet>` instead of `List<object>`.  And `AddPet` would have taken an `IPet` instead of `object`.  That would have greatly simplified your `IntroduceAll` method.

Comment: I think that 7.8 is rather high for code that uses `== typeof()` for polymorphism.

Comment: Notice any repetitive code in your cat & dog?

Comment: I'm guessing "implement exception handling" meant to check for `null` being passed to `AddPet` not creating a custom exception type to use.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One mistake could be using `List<Object>` in your class `PetShop`

```
List<Object> objList = new List<object>();
```

instead you could have a `List<IPet>` and then your method `AddPet` should expect a parameter of type `IPet` , add `Cat` and `Dog` objects to that list. Later in your method `IntroduceAll` you could have done:

```
public void IntroduceAll()
{
    foreach (IPet element in objList)
    {
      element.Introduce();
    }
}
```

**instead of comparing types and then calling `Introduce` method**, this would show the polymorphic behaviour.

Other thing could be having a parameterized constructor, since you are instantiating the objects for `Cat` and `Dog` and then setting properties.

Answer (score 6):

I think the biggest gap is that you are not using polymorphism at all. You are defining an interface `IPet` and deriving your animals from it. But then, you use type checks.

You can verify this by removing `IPet`. Your code will run anyway.

You should always use `IPet` in your later code like your data list and the loop.

Comment: Yeah, you are right

Answer (score 6):

Tweaking a little further based on comments from @Henk and @Mikko mentioned is that you are using TypeOf and also copied and pasted the body of the Cat and Dog classes when you could use an abstract class and accomplish the same goal once:

```
abstract class PetStoreAnimal : IPet
{
    string name;
    string breed;
    public string MyName { get {return name; } set {name = value;} }

    public string MyBreed { get {return breed; } set {breed = value;} }

    public void Introduce()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("I am {0} of {1} and I am a {2}", MyName, MyBreed, this.GetType().Name));
    }
}
```

This reduces the repetition, and then Cat and Dog effectively become:

```
 class Cat : PetStoreAnimal
{
    public Cat()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Nice first post! I would add that the vertical whitespace could be reduced to enhance readability here (getter/setter would each be 1 line), and private fields could be `readonly` and `camelCase`, with the property name matching the backing field - actually, these properties are so trivial they could be implemented as auto-properties.

Comment: You can omit the empty public constructor - those are generated by default.

Comment: @DanLyons you're right, it's unnecessary, I do tend to be explicit with these things.  When someone is learning, things that happen without them doing it adds confusion, so I left it for that reason.  Thanks for pointing it out though, it's important :)

Answer (score 5):

**TL;DR You should be very happy with a score of 7.8**

Now, to be honest I am a tough marker :) So, if I was marking this I would mark you down for each of these issues:

`namespace ConsoleApplication1` - give it a meaningful namespace instead.

`interface IPet`, `class Dog : IPet` etc - always use an access modifier, eg `public interface IPet`, `public class Dog`

`public string MyName { ... }` - properties should use automatic getters and setters, eg `public string MyName { get; set; }`

`public string MyName { ... }` - the requirements specifically said that the properties must be `Name` and `Breed`, you have `MyName` and `MyBreed`.

`public Cat()` - you should include name and breed in the constructor so that it can be passed in when the variable is created.

Not using the obvious superclass / subclass relationship:

```
public abstract class Animal : IPet 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Breed { get; }
    public string Introduce()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("I am {0} of {1}. I'm a {2}", 
                          Name, Breed, this.GetType().Name));
    }
}

public class Cat : Animal
{
    public Cat(string name, string breed) { Name = name; Breed = breed; }
}   // repeat this for Dog
```

And also for:

`List<Object> objList = new List<object>();` should be `List<IPet> pets = new List<IPet>();` - use the actual interface you have, and name the variable properly.

`public void IntroduceAll()` should be implemented very simply now that you have an actual list of `IPet` to work with:  `foreach (var pet in pets) { pet.Introduce(); }`

As for the requirement to use exceptions, this means you need to handle an exception. Not create a new exception variable and try to add it to your pets list. Something like:

```
try
{
    petshop.Add(new Cat());
    petshop.Add(new Dog());
    petshop.Add(new Animal()); // change petshop so it throws an exception here
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // handle the exception here
}
```

Your `Introduce` method does not output the exact string that was requested: "I'm (Name) of (Breed). I'm a cat (or dog)".  Yours says "I'm (Name) of (Breed) I'm a cat (or dog)" instead.  You missed the full stop - I know this is picky, but details matter.

And some more points off for naming:

- `PetShop ps = new PetShop();` - use the whole name, `var petshop = new PetShop();` to be clear.
- `Cat pussy = new Cat();` - are you trying to be cute here? Just use `var cat = new Cat()`

So, you wouldn't be getting a very high score sorry. You haven't actually implemented any polymorphism, you haven't handled exceptions as requested, and your properties do not match the names required.  Attention to detail matters :)

Comment: Why should he always use an access modifier? And Breed has no setter, your code does not seem to compile.